# ASP.NET Razor VB.NET - Uploaded Images are upside-down. How to fix?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net, razor

I have an ASP.NET Webpages Razor syntax VB.NET Website.

I have recently added in the feature to upload images with great success.

However when viewing the image on the website any picture is upside-down!
The original files are of the correct orientation however upon viewing through the website using the `<img>` tags I get the issue.

I have one other static image in my site and this is not flipped. It is only the files that I upload. Even files downloaded from the internet and uploaded come out on the page as upside down!

So right now I am using:

```
<img src="/Docs/Events/1676/image1.JPG" height="400" width="400">
```

Using developer tools through chrome I can request the image directly. This shows the image correctly!

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: There isn't anything in that `img` tag which would cause that.  Nor does this have anything to do with .NET or Razor.  I *suspect* that the images actually *are* upside down, but have meta-data included within them to suggest a different orientation.  And not everything which displays an image uses that meta-data.

Comment: I would have agreed with you, although a request just for the image provides the image in the correct orientation. Also, In my file explorer on the server the image is correct and this doesn't matter what image I use, even one from the internet, its still upside down when displayed in the web page